# Django Diplay Data leafleft

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I am learning djnago , I would like to display an html page (in template forlder) into another html file by keeping {% extends 'base.html' %} which my template HTML that has my nav bar, CSS , javascritp..

the structure:

```
App1=>templates=>App1=>map.html (is a map app html file generated with folium https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/)

App1=>templates=>App1=>home.html
Src=>templates=>base.html
```

in home.html I would like to diplay map.html and all base.html elements (nav bar, CSS, javasript)

Here is my base .html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- semantic UI -->

    <!--Chart js-->



    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>skill-site | {% block title %}    {% endblock title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body> 


 {% include 'navbar.html' %}
 {% block scripts %}
 {% endblock scripts %}

<div class="container ui">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is the code for home.html but it is not working:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}my map{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

{% include './map.html' %} 

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `{% include 'App1/map.html' %}`?

Comment: I do not think the path is the problem cause I can see the map code when I inspect the page

Comment: Maybe it is because avec "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">" included in 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

Comment: Show us your `map.html` as well, but if you are seeing the map code, what exactly are you asking? I ask because the question is tagged as django/python, but from the looks of it it's more of HTML/JS.

Comment: it is a big html how can I send it?

Comment: What do you mean by send? Give details about your question.

Comment: map.html is an html file generated with folium :https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/